# SSRS 2008 R2 Subscribtion tab missing from report

Tags: ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

i'm just started by using SSRS 2008 R2. When i try to subscribe my report, Subscription tab is not shown and also i'm not able to subscribe my report by right click on the report and select subscribe option.

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you are using I.E. I.E. natively supports SSRS, where as other browsers don't work that well.

Also please make sure that within the SSRS, Site Settings, security you are under the System Administrator/ System User role. Otherwise you may not be able to see the subscriptions.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I'm using IE for this purpose, and my account is under System Administrator role but still it is not working for me.